# IntelliJ This class already exists conflict between main and test directory

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm trying to name my class Util inside the src/test directory. However, another class with this same name already exists inside src/main, and IntelliJ is blocking me from doing this renaming. Funny thing is that the class inside the test folder was already named Util and that was fine before, but today IntelliJ started complaining about it and was no longer finding my methods inside that class, looking for them inside the Util class inside src/main instead.

I tried deleting the idea folder and reloading the project, but the same error is still there and I'm not sure how to fix it.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: you can't have classes with the same fully qualified name (is that really surprising, though?)

Comment: They are under different directories though. I may be mistaken but I'd have expected src/main and src/test not to conflict with each other.

Comment: directories don't matters once the classes are packaged together. only the fully qualified name (package + class name). Otherwise, in a context where both are accessible, when you import it, how do you know which one is imported?

Comment: Thank you. Understand. If you'd like to make this into an answer I can mark it as accepted.